# Use Conditional Formatting in Google Sheets to highlight cell

Tags: regex, checkbox, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

**Problem**

I want to be able to highlight a cell in google sheets if a cell on the same row is TRUE and the value does not exist in a named range (or a sheet).

e.g.

Based on the scenario below in sheet1, if column a is TRUE, and the value in column b does not match anything in sheet2, highlight the cell red.

```
sheet1
column a     column b
TRUE         value1
FALSE        value2

sheet2 
column a 
value2
```

I would like to do this in google sheets using conditional formatting custom formulas and named ranges (if required).

**Edit**

I have tried this with my sheet but cant manage it... I have copied my sheet example below! Are you able to work it with this?

**sheet1**
[image]

**sheet2**
[image]

**Edit 2**

Rather than just matching whats in Cell D I would like to only match the values of the string that is separated by commas and only search if the letters "tf" are in the string.

Answer (score 0):

> if column a is TRUE, and the value in column b does not match anything in sheet2, highlight the cell red

try:

```
=(A1=TRUE)*(NOT(REGEXMATCH(B1&"", ""&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, INDIRECT("Sheet2!A:A")))))
```

[image: 4]

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eI9FTVNuyMEzQTJnHzufz_gElE53AMmk-mxVEWKPdRk/edit?usp=sharing

Please request access.

Comment: Any luck with this player0?

Comment: I have made the sheet public... https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eI9FTVNuyMEzQTJnHzufz_gElE53AMmk-mxVEWKPdRk/edit?usp=sharing